# Understanding extended binomial theorem for coefficient in square roots

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

In the question, compute the coefficient of $x^{7}$ in $\sqrt{1-7x}$

How come $\sqrt{1-7x}$ can result in a coefficient for $x^{7}$?

Is there some generating function that I don’t see? Or does it it work for any function?

The answer is $$ \left(\frac{1}{_2 C_7} \right) \cdot -7^{7} $$

I know the algorithm, but I don’t see how it works for square roots? As far as I understand, once you have your generating function you plug stuff into the extended binomial theorem assuming that there is a composite function. Then you multiply the combination by the coefficient from the original generating function.

Hence the answer, $ \left(\frac{1}{_2 C_7} \right) \cdot -7^{7} $

Comment: are you talking about [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)?

Comment: I don't understand the confusion.  $\frac 1{1-x}$ has a coefficient for $x^7$ for example.  So what?  Just compute the Taylor Series.

Comment: @lulu I never directly learned taylor series. I don’t see how this relates to sqrt(1-7x)

Comment: Well, do you know the binomial series (for things other than natural numbers)?

Comment: @lulu no, only the generating functions for 1/(1-x), 1/(1+x), (1-x^(n+1)/(1-x), and 1/(1-nx)

Comment: I don't know how you are meant to solve this problem, then.  But your title specifically references the extended binomial theorem, after all.

Comment: @lulu that’s just because I might need to find combinations with fractional or negative numbers and this problem its done on 1/2

Comment: Right, so apply the extended binomial theorem with exponent $\frac 12$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107607/discussion-between-matthew-wyatt-and-lulu).

Comment: No need for a chat.  This question is literally an application of the extended binomial theorem.  Just write down what that theorem says and you will have your answer.

Comment: @lulu im confused because normally I would use it and then use the generating function to finish the problem. For example, coefficient of x^7 in sqrt(1/1-7x). Would that not be (1/2)C7*(-7)^7(-1)^7? I’m confused as to how the 1-7x manages to generate a coefficient for x^7.       the chat was accidental btw

Comment: The binomial theorem says:  $(1+z)^{\alpha}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom {\alpha }kz^k$.  Taking $z=-7x$ and $\alpha =\frac 12$ we see that $(1-7x)^{1/2}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom {-1/2}k (-7)^kx^k$ and we are done.

Comment: Note:  Typo in that formula,  Shoiuld have read $\binom {1/2}k$, the $-\frac 12$ was a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Letting $[x^n]\,f(x)$ denote the coefficient of $x^n$ in the Maclaurin series of $f(x)$, we have
$$\begin{eqnarray*}[x^7]\sqrt{1-7x}&=&7^7\cdot [x^7]\sqrt{1-x}= 7^6\cdot[x^6]\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{1-x}\\&=&-\frac{7^6}{2}[x^6]\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}=\color{red}{-\frac{7^6}{2\cdot 4^6}\binom{12}{6}}\end{eqnarray*} $$
due to the well-known $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}x^n$.

Answer (score 1):

The generalized binomial theorem states that,
for $|x| < 1$,
we have
$(1+x)^a
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{a}{n} x^n
$
where
$\binom{a}{n}
=\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (a-k)}{n!}
$.

For $a = \frac12$ this is
$\binom{\frac12}{n}
=\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (\frac12-k)}{n!}
=\dfrac{ (\frac12)(-\frac12)(-\frac32)...(-\frac12-n+1)}{n!}
$.

The first few successive values are

$
\binom{\frac12}{1}
=\dfrac{\frac12}{1}
=\frac12\\
\binom{\frac12}{2}
=\dfrac{\frac12(-\frac12)}{2!}
=-\frac18\\
\binom{\frac12}{3}
=\dfrac{\frac12(-\frac12)(-\frac32)}{3!}
=\frac1{16}\\
\binom{\frac12}{4}
=\dfrac{\frac12(-\frac12)(-\frac32)(-\frac52)}{4!}
=-\frac{5}{128}\\
...\\
\binom{\frac12}{7}
=\dfrac{\frac12(-\frac12)(-\frac32)(-\frac52)(-\frac72)(-\frac92)(-\frac{11}{2})}{7!}
=\frac{33}{2048}\\
$

Putting $-7x$ for $x$
we get
$(1-7x)^{1/2}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{\frac12}{n} (-7x)^n
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{\frac12}{n} (-7)^nx^n
$
so the coefficient of $x^7$ is
$\binom{\frac12}{7}(-1)^77^7
=-\frac{33}{2048}7^7
=-\frac{27176919}{2048}.
$

Note that,
for $n \ge 2$,

$\begin{array}\\
\binom{\frac12}{n}
&=\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (\frac12-k)}{n!}\\
&=\dfrac12\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (\frac12-k)}{n!}\\
&=\dfrac12\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (1-2k)}{2^{n-1}n!}\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2}\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (2k-1)}{2^{n-1}n!}\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2}\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} ((2k-1)(2k))}{2^{n-1}n!\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(2k)}\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2}\dfrac{(2n-2)!}{2^{n-1}n!2^{n-1}(n-1)!}\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}(2n-2)!}{2^{2n-1}n!(n-1)!}\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}(2n)!}{(2n-1)2^{2n}n!^2}\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n-1)4^{n}}\binom{2n}{n}\\
\end{array}
$